# BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses exception when using wildcard queries

Tags: java, exception, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search / Lucene to maintain a really simple index to find objects by name - no fancy stuff.

My model classes all extend a class `NamedModel` which looks basically as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class NamedModel {
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED)
    protected String name;
}
```

My problem is that I get a `BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses` exception when querying the index for objects with names starting with a specific letter, e.g. `"name:l*"`.
A query like `"name:lin*"` will work without problems, in fact any query using more than one letter before the wildcard will work.

While searching the net for similar problems, I only found people using pretty complex queries and that always seemed to cause the exception. I don't want to increase `maxClauseCount` because I don't think it's a good practice to change limits just because you reach them.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene tries to rewrite your query from simple `name:l*` to a query with all terms starting with l in them (something like `name:lou OR name:la OR name: ...`) - I believe as this is meant to be faster.

As a workaround, you may use a `ConstantScorePrefixQuery` instead of a `PrefixQuery`:

```
// instead of new PrefixQuery(prefix)
new ConstantScoreQuery(new PrefixFilter(prefix));
```

However, this changes scoring of documents (hence sorting if you rely on score for sorting). As we faced the challenge of needing score (and boost), we decided to go for a solution where we use `PrefixQuery` if possible and fallback to `ConstantScorePrefixQuery` where needed:

```
new PrefixQuery(prefix) {
  public Query rewrite(final IndexReader reader) throws IOException {
    try {
      return super.rewrite(reader);
    } catch (final TooManyClauses e) {
      log.debug("falling back to ConstantScoreQuery for prefix " + prefix + " (" + e + ")");
      final Query q = new ConstantScoreQuery(new PrefixFilter(prefix));
      q.setBoost(getBoost());
      return q;
    }
  }
};
```

(As an enhancement, one could use some kind of `LRUMap` to cache terms that failed before to avoid going through a costly rewrite again)

I can't help you with integrating this into Hibernate Search though. You might ask after you've switched to [Compass](http://www.compass-project.org/) ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. As far as I can tell there's no direct way to change the generated `Query` type for Hibernate Search. But I changed the analyzer used to `KeywordAnalyer` which doesn't generate defunct queries and also fits my needs better.